# IOS UITableView frame change action not firing when I use auto layout constraint to update its frame height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, frame

I am doing something about chat room; I use a `uitableview` to display chat history and `uiview` as container for text input & emoji. The `uitableview` has constraint 0 bottom to the text input & emoji view; when I expand the height constraint of the text input & emoji view, the frame of `uitableview` is updated, but the change action is not fired in code.

[image]

I have tried the following code to observe the change but it doesn't work.

```
-(void)didChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key
-(void)willChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key
[_tableView.layer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil\];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also tried this once for tracking changes in native properties. But I think this observers are triggered only when properties set **through setter methods**. Like,

```
self.myProperty = newValue;
```

If you use,

```
_myProperty = newValue;
```

your observer will not get any changes in key-value observing.

In the case of native elements like `tableView`, we don't know the internal implementation. To track changes, you have to customise your `tableView`.

Comment: yeah, i think so, the update frame value through private attribute not the setter method. i get  a hook

Comment: yeah, i think so, the update frame value through private attribute not the setter method. i get  a hook method invoked at where i change the constraint, it works. but how i can i track the frame change if i customize tableview?

Comment: @JaxHuang In your case `expand the height constraint of the text input & emoji view` is the related event of tableView `frame` change and definitely you have the control there. There you can trigger other event using notification or delegate to perform subsequent steps.